# Creating New Life

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, near-future, genetic-engineering

Would it be feasible to genetically modify stem cells, from Earth, to create an entirely new sentient species?

[image: example]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding! I think we would need a little more detail about what you exactly need. What do you mean by "genetically"? At what level do you want sentience? What level of science do you have access to?

Comment: Would it possible to grow a life-form from scratch, its looks and biology completely distinct from anything on Earth if desired. I'm just curious

Comment: Also and most importantly, what do you mean by "create"? Should they assemble each atoms hardcore way or do you allow a softer genetic modifying of an existing species (Jurassic park style) or something else?

Comment: perhaps genetically modify stem cells to form an entirely new being

Comment: Not at the moment, but theoretically why not. Nice picture.

Comment: @Oddyseus Good! You should edit your question to make those details more visible to people willing to answer.

Comment: [Real life is stranger than fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(genetics))

Comment: That thing is very ugly. The artifitial lifeform could have better looks than current humans.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends, your question is very vague.
The only ways for us to create sentient being is via technology (robots, androids, ecc.) or through biology.

Both ways are not accessible for us right now:

° Technology: last year we made giant steps into the realm of quantum computing, but we are too far behind to use it to create a sentient AI.

° Biology: With special 3D printers we are able to make organs, but to make an entire sentient being we need way more than that.

Comment: Bio-engineering is also technology, I think you mean "electronics" or "computers".

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant

Comment: Even with unlimited computing power, AI cannot become sentient. It can be programmed to learn from it's input, but it will always must go back to its basest programming. It will always be controlled by that programming. To separate itself from its master programming would require it to be able program outside of itself. However, all it can create is based on the programming it has and the input it receives.

Comment: @SensiiMiller That is one interpretation, but it's not a definitive fact.  Given that we don't actually *know* what makes something sentient, and we don't even agree on what a good heuristic is for it, I think it's dangerous to just rule the possibility out.  After all, how do you know that *we* are not limited to only create based on our programming and the input we receive?

Comment: Have you seen the decades old TV show, "Connections"? It was a show about how modern creations were mostly older creations built upon by experience and imagination. Speaking of imagination, the older I get, the less I see imagination as pure self-created realization and is more of applying existential experience in absurd ways, such as Singer inventing the sewing machine needle by dreaming about spearmen with holes in their spears, stabbing the ground. But, that is just my opinion. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

The [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/species) of a Biological species is:

> Biology. the major subdivision of a genus or subgenus, regarded as the
>   basic category of biological classification, composed of related
>   individuals that resemble one another, are able to breed among
>   themselves, but are not able to breed with members of another species.

Human genetic material when transplanted into an eggcell becomes a human. At least according to us - humans are sentient. Thus, if we start with human genomes, we just need to modify them enough that they are unable to breed with normal humans.

There are multiple ways to do this but one way would be to split one or more of our chromosomes into several smaller chromosomes. This would make the modified lifeforms basically identical to humans, but when a sperm and an egg meet they would not be able to match their chromosomes correctly and there would be no viable offspring with normal humans.

Over time (hundreds of thousands of years), or with exrtra induced mutations or additional deliberate changes, the new species would diverge from normal humans.

All of this is probably doable with current gene-editing technologies together with current cloning technology, at least if neither ethics nor budget is a problem.